# Redirecting awk output using value of variable name

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to awk the first column1 and then using sort -u and create file with column1 values using ask and Ksh ,

```
       for i in `cat /u01/test/test.csv | awk -F , '{print $1}' | sort -u`
       do
       {
       log=/u01/test
       CLS="LEFT"
       cat $log/test.csv|grep $i|awk -v v1=$log -v v3=$CLS -v v4=$i  '{FS = ","}
       {printf("\<TR class\=%s height\=22\>\n",v3) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html";}

       {if ($2 == "ENG" || $2 == "HIN")
       {printf("\<TD class\=yellow align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s \<\/TD\>\n",$1) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html";
       printf("\<TD class\=yellow align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s \<\/TD\>\n",$2) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html";
       printf("\<TD class\=yellow align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s \<\/TD\>\n",$3) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html"}
       else
       {
       printf("\<TD class\=%s align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s\<\/TD\>\n",v3,$1) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html";
       printf("\<TD class\=%s align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s\<\/TD\>\n",v3,$2) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html";
       printf("\<TD class\=%s align\=left height\=\"17\" width\=\"10\%%\"\>%s\<\/TD\>\n",v3,$3) >> v1/"${v4}-test.html"}}
       {if (v3~"RED"){v3 = "YELLOW"} else {v3 = "RED"}}
       {printf("\<\/TR\>\n") >> v1/{v4}-test.html}'
       }
       done
```

But this is not creating file with column1 unique values

sample Input

LANG,ENG,HIN
REG,USA,TEXAS
LANG,ENG,SIB
REG,UK,EUROPE

Sample Output

Two outputfiles names LANG-test.html and REGI-test.html

Contents of LANG-test.html

```
       <TR Class=CLS height=22>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>LANG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>ENG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>HIN</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>LANG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>ENG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>SIB</TD>
       </TR>
```

and other File with name REG-test.html

```
       <TR Class=CLS height=22>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>REG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>USA</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>TEXAS</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>LANG</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>UK</TD>
       <TD class=yellow align=left height=17 width=10>EUR</TD>
       </TR>
```

Trying to findout the error on printf statement beacuse awk unable to parse lines in printf and secondly the redirection of output based on unique 1st column is challenging

Comment: please share sample Input_file and expected output into your post too in code tags.

Comment: there are several issues in your script that should be fixed, but you need to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that runs with awk only. It was too many comments on details so I just wrote it up.

```
log=/u01/test
CLS="LEFT"
awk -F, -v v1=$log -v v3=$CLS '
  { printf("<TR class=%s height=22>\n",v3) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html";
    if ($2 == "ENG" || $2 == "HIN") {
      printf("<TD class=yellow align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s </TD>\n",$1) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html";
      printf("<TD class=yellow align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s </TD>\n",$2) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html";
      printf("<TD class=yellow align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s </TD>\n",$3) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html" }
    else {
      printf("<TD class=%s align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s</TD>\n",v3,$1) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html";
      printf("<TD class=%s align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s</TD>\n",v3,$2) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html";
      printf("<TD class=%s align=left height=\"17\" width=\"10%\">%s</TD>\n",v3,$3) >> v1"/"$1"-test.html" }
    if (v3~"RED") { v3 = "YELLOW" } else {v3 = "RED"}
    printf("</TR>\n") >> v1"/"$1"-test.html"
  }' $log/test.csv
```

Note the changes on string concatenation, variable usage and escaping characters. The for loop is gone because there was no point in it. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can work with `BEGIN{...}` and `END{...}` if you need that TR markup to occur only once per file. @sam_84